# Infiltrating in new Caprica

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

Suppose you are playing a game with a Cylon leader. He is not infiltrating. The humans reach New Caprica. Is there now no mechanic by which a Cylon Leader can infiltrate? So the only way for a Cylon leader to infiltrate is for him to already have been infiltrating when we arrived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct; there is no way for a Cylon leader to start infiltrating while on New Caprica. (See the [Unofficial FAQ at BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Battlestar_Galactica%3a_Pegasus_Expansion_Unofficial_FAQ#toc3))

If a Cylon leader needs the humans to win and wants to be able to help them out on New Caprica, s/he needs to be infiltrating when they get there. Otherwise, s/he won't be able to use the **Human** actions, which is the main way to help the humans.

Comment: Makes perfect in-universe sense: once arrived on New Caprica, the humans get to see *many* multiple copies of each model... kinda hard for a random Cylon to start infiltrating at that point.  A Cylon who wants humans to win should, you know, join the humans.  ;)